# DatePicker works but Autocomplete does not when publish

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, publish

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC Application.. and everything works fine while testing with the *localhost*... but when I publish my application only the *datepicker* works.  I have checked the folder of which my Scripts are being published to, and searched the jQuery UI script to see if it included the *auto-complete* and it did.

I am receiving 0 errors in the console, and all of *script* links are correct.  I am running jQuery 1.10.2.

The only thing I could find while I was **Inspecting Element** on the webpage was:

```
<input name="subcategory" class="form-control text-box single-line ui-autocomplete-input ui-autocomplete-loading" id="Categories" type="text" value="" data-val-required="This field is required!" data-val="true" autocomplete="off">
```

I changed the `autocomplete="off"` to `autocomplete="on"` and that still didn't make it work.

I am not sure on what other code I should post with this to help give you all a better understanding because it all works while I test the application in localhost.

How is it that 1 part of *jQuery UI* works but the other doesn't?

Do I have to add a reference that has something to do with ajax since my autocomplete uses that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Categories').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/codeAC/AutoCompleteCategory",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.subcategory, value: item.subcategory };
                }))
            }
        })
    },
});
});
```

needed to be changed to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Categories').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "//*folder on server name*//codeAC/AutoCompleteCategory",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.subcategory, value: item.subcategory };
                }))
            }
        })
    },
});
});
```